# Nativescript не удаётся запустить на реальном телефоне- только виртуалка

Tags: javascript, android, ios, android-emulator, nativescript

У меня перестали запускаться приложения Nativescript на телефоне.
Раньше в командрой строке отображался QR код затем я мог протестировать приложение у себя на телефоне. Сейчас запускается виртуальный телефон.(*ну я поустанавливал кучу лишнего,а сейчас откатиться не могу)*
Подскажите 
**1. - Что нужно изменить, что б получить QR и работать с телефоном
2.Как подключить виртуальный Iphone для тестирования?**

Спасибо

Дополнение - с первым разобрался

```
tns preview
```

Comment: > tns run ios --emulator

Comment: 1) > tns preview --link
2) copy the link
3) > open the link in the Emulator